# How to get an XML response from the googleapi Youtube API

Tags: xml, youtube, google-api, youtube-data-api

It seems that YouTube has updated their API to a newer one ([YouTube Data API (v3)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)), and suddenly the YouTube searches on my site are not working.

I am trying to update them to work with the new API, but every time I get a `JSON` result, instead of `XML`, the old API returned xml so my code expects a xml return result. When I tried to specify XML in the call to the API, I got an error that the call is invalid.

Can anyone please explain to me how I can retrieve an XML from the YouTube API V3?

Answer (score 6):

The [YouTube API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) returns data in [JSon](http://json.org/). It is not possible to change it to return xml.

> Prerequisites
>
> 1. Register your application with Google so that it can submit API requests.
> 2. Familiarize yourself with the core concepts of the JSON (JavaScript 
>      Object Notation) data format. For more information,
>      see [json.org](http://json.org/).