# How to get youtube API 3 response as XML instead of JSON?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Currently I'm using youtube api v3 to retrive single video information as:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=rQbOoUmhSPo&part=snippet&key=[mykey]

Result is JSON.

How can I get the result in XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a duplicate question. Here is about the same question: [How to get an XML response from the googleapi Youtube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153111/how-to-get-an-xml-response-from-the-googleapi-youtube-api)

So it isn't possible through the API, you could try to convert the json object to XML but i don't know in which programming language you are working so can't help you any further.